# MySQL "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, mariadb, sequelize.js

I have the follwing SQL commands:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` 
  ( 
     `id`        INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     `username`  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
     `password`  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
     `root`      TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0, 
     `createdat` DATETIME NOT NULL, 
     `updatedat` DATETIME NOT NULL, 
     UNIQUE `username_unique` (`username`), 
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
  ) 
engine=innodb; 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `domains` 
  ( 
     `id`        INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     `domain`    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
     `createdat` DATETIME NOT NULL, 
     `updatedat` DATETIME NOT NULL, 
     `userid`    INTEGER, 
     UNIQUE `domain_unique` (`domain`), 
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
     FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON 
     UPDATE CASCADE 
  ) 
engine=innodb; 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `aliases` 
  ( 
     `id`                   INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     `source_username`      VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
     `source_domain`        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
     `destination_username` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
     `destination_domain`   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
     `enabled`              TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, 
     `createdat`            DATETIME NOT NULL, 
     `updatedat`            DATETIME NOT NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
     FOREIGN KEY (`source_domain`) REFERENCES `domains` (`domain`) 
  ) 
engine=innodb; 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts` 
  ( 
     `id`        INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     `username`  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
     `domain`    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
     `password`  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
     `quota`     INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 500, 
     `enabled`   TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, 
     `sendonly`  TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
     `createdat` DATETIME NOT NULL, 
     `updatedat` DATETIME NOT NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
     FOREIGN KEY (`domain`) REFERENCES `domains` (`domain`) 
  ) 
engine=innodb;
```

if i try to run these i get the message:

> "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

for the tables Alias and Accounts.

Its not possible to use primary keys in alias and accounts

Im using MariaDB 10.2

I hope somebody can tell me what is wrong with these statements.

Comment: Why is mysql in your title but mariadb in your text? Which is it? Please edit your tags & you title or body. PS This is a duplicate/faq, please don't ask when you can google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a key/index to the `domain` field of the `domains` table, in order for it to be used as Foreign Key by another table.

**If the table is already created and you want to add an index, use this.**

> CREATE INDEX domain ON domains(domain);

**OR add the index while creating the table -**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `domains` 
  ( 
     `id`        INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     `domain`    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
     `createdat` DATETIME NOT NULL, 
     `updatedat` DATETIME NOT NULL, 
     `userid`    INTEGER, 
     UNIQUE `domain_unique` (`domain`), 
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
     INDEX domain (domain),
     FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON 
     UPDATE CASCADE 
  ) 
engine=innodb;
```

For further reading (official documentation) regarding Foreign Key Contraint Errors on MariaDB [this URL](https://mariadb.org/mariadb-innodb-foreign-key-constraint-errors/)

Answer (score 0):

You define an integer primary key.  Use it:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `aliases` 
  ( 
     `id`                   INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     `source_username`      VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
     `source_domain_id`     INTEGER NOT NULL, 
     `destination_username` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
     `destination_domain`   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
     `enabled`              TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, 
     `createdat`            DATETIME NOT NULL, 
     `updatedat`            DATETIME NOT NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
     FOREIGN KEY (`source_domain_id`) REFERENCES `domains` (`id`) 
  ) 
engine=innodb;
```

Comment: i would, but this needs to interpreted by postfix, so i need the information as string

Comment: @FabianS. He means the FK must be the same type as the PK. Read the documentation. Read about 'RTFM'.